# SQL, выбрать ненулевую запись - либо первую, либо первую после последнего нуля

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть таблица вида

```
id     value
       2
       5
       15
       0
       12
       0
       6
       10
```

нужно SQL запросом(Firebird) выбрать запись с ненулевым value после последнего нуля(т.е. с value = 6), либо, если в таблице нет строк с value = 0, то первую запись.

Comment: а что вы называете `после`? Та запись у которой id следующий по порядку?

Comment: Таблица - это несортированная куча. Понятие "после", "перед", "последний" и т.п. в ней - НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ. До тех пор пока не выполнена сортировка (в запросе! не в самой таблице) по выражению, по которому каждая запись уникальна. Здесь сортировки нет.

Comment: Да, виноват - запись "после" - это запись с большим ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebird не знаю. Но тут все по стандарту:

```
select val from test where id=
(select min (id) from test where val<>0
and id>(select coalesce(max(id),0) id from test where val=0)
);
```

Comment: Хм, а если в таблице есть дополнительная колонка - категория и нужно сделать то же самое, но в каждой категории?

create table test (
id integer,
  sid integer,
val integer
);

Answer (score 0):

Решение может быть таким в случае если `id` следуют строго по порядку:

```
create table test (
id integer,
val integer
);

insert into test (id, val) value (1,1);
insert into test (id, val) value (2,0);
insert into test (id, val) value (3,6);
insert into test (id, val) value (4,9);
insert into test (id, val) value (5,0);
insert into test (id, val) value (6,8);
insert into test (id, val) value (7,2);

select 
case when t.target is null then tt.val else t.target end as val  
from (
  select val from test order by id asc limit 1
  ) as tt
left join (
  select 
    case when t1.val = 0 then t2.val else null end as target
  from test t1
  inner join test t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
  where case when t1.val = 0 then t2.val else null end is not null
  order by t1.id DESC
  limit 1
) as t on 1 = 1
```

Пример на mysql, для firebird нужно переписать `limit`.

[Рабочий пример](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9cANGafnzjuLRxkGh9PeUj/0)